# How do I make Tess4J accurately read TIFF image after threshold has been applied?

Tags: java, ocr, tesseract, tess4j

I am very new to Tess4J so my knowledge is somewhat limited. I am currently using Tess4j to do OCR on an image that has already had a threshold applied to it using OpenCV. I'm using OTSU to threshold the image, and cropping out most noise, but Tesseract doesn't seem to be able to read the numbers at all. I've read that the size can alter recognition but even when I scale the image it doesn't seem to work. Is there more I need to do to the Image or use a different .traindata to do OCR?

This is my code for Tess4J's OCR.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File imageFile = new File("newim.TIFF");
    Tesseract instance = new Tesseract(); // JNA Interface Mapping
    instance.setDatapath("workspace/Tess4J/tessdata");
    instance.setLanguage("Interstate");


    try {
        String result = instance.doOCR(imageFile);
        System.out.println(result);
    } catch (TesseractException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

[Image I'm trying to do OCR on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Uwvz.jpg)

Result: "EEEH"

Comment: It seems cropping out the non-text parts (vertical bars on the sides) would yield the correct result.

Comment: After removing the non-text parts it only recognizes "Speed Limit" and not the numbers